# Windows Azure Web Jobs is in Preview, is it fine to use it in Production?

Tags: azure, preview, azure-webjobs

I am new to windows azure, and recently working on an implementation suggested by Richard diZerega, on [How to implement timer jobs for SharePoint Online](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/04/07/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-as-windows-azure-web-jobs.aspx).

In this blog Richard suggested to use web jobs. Which is all fine but, I was unsure if its fine to implement it in production, as the feature is in preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is still in preview so as CSharpRocks mentioned the support policies are going to be different. Please read this for more information on the support policies for preview features http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/

Answer (score 1):

Sure as long that you're aware that preview = beta and that there's no SLA with services in preview.